# Malbim on the irrationality/illegitimacy of Amalek

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, army-military-war, samuel-shmuel-book-of, amalek

[Malbim on Shmuel 1:15:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.15.2?lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_I_Samuel.15.2.1&lang2=bi) writes about the irrationality, or perhaps the illegitimacy of Amalek's war with Bnei Yisrael:

> "כה אמר ה' צבאות,  הנה התורה בארה בטעם מצות מיחוי זכר עמלק כמה טעמים כמ"ש זכור את אשר עשה לך עמלק בדרך בצאתכם ממצרים אשר קרך בדרך ויזנב בך כל הנחשלים אחריך ואתה עיף ויגע ולא ירא אלהים רצה לומר כי כל עורכי מלחמות יהיו באחד מחמשה פנים. א) או שילחם על ארץ לכבשה להגדיל את ארצו, וזה היה בדרך כי לא היית אז בארץ נושבת, ב) אם יקרב עם אל גבול ארצו ילחם עמו מיראתו פן יעבור בגבולו, כמו מלחמת סיחון ועוג, וזה היה בצאתכם ממצרים שהייתם רחוקים מארצו, ג) מחמת איזה מריבה ומשטמה שיש בין שני העמים הלוחמים אבל הוא קרך בדרך דרך מקרה ולא היה לו דבר עמך, ד) להראות גבורתו ותקפו להיות לו לשם, אבל הוא זנב כל הנחשלים ואתה עיף ויגע בענין שלא כיון להראות כח בקרב ה) בעבור הדת שחושב שה' ירצה מעשיו שיכחיד אומה הבלתי מאמנת בדתו ואלהיו, והוא לא ירא אלהים,  בענין שמלחמתו לא היה לה שום סבה מן הסבות שבעבורם יתגרו מלחמות,"

Malbim brings five legitimate reasons for war and proceeds to explain how Amalek didn't fulfill any of these reasons:

1. Conquest of land - the war between Amalek and Yisrael was in unsettled territory, so it wasn't about conquering land.
2. Defensive war (a nation defending its territory) - again, the wilderness was unsettled and not controlled by Amalek; the land of Amalek was far away.
3. A dispute or two-way hatred - but in this case, it was an accidental meeting, there were no prior interactions.
4. To show courage and strength - but Amalek opened their attack by attacking the slow and the weak of Yisrael.
5. Religious reasons - fear of Hashem destroying that nation's religion - but on Amalek it is explicitly stated that they did not fear Hashem.

Therefore, according to Malbim, Amalek did not have any legitimate reason to fight Yisrael. Malbim proceeds and explains that Amalek attacked for two reasons: Hatred of Hashem and hatred of the descendants of Yaakov.

Why doesn't Malbim list looting and plundering as a reason for war? After all, Yisrael left Egypt rich and were even more so after Yam Suf, and a group short on supplies and wealth could benefit greatly from attacking them. Perhaps that is why Amalek attacked Yisrael, or at least one of the reasons.

Comment: I think the answer is that Malbim knew the conclusion before the proof. The proof isn't a rigorous proof for the sake of proving his later point, but just a teaching device to help him make the actual point that he was coming to make - that Amalek went beyond reason to do evil against Hashem's people. Does that make sense?

Comment: Did the stragglers have wealth?

Comment: Does it say that they plundered the Jews?